# Store data in an array using for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
var cart = {};
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cart.item_name = items[i].get("item_name");
    cart.quantity = items[i].get("quantity");
    cart.amount =  items[i].get("amount");
    cart.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;
    cart.subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total;
     }
console.log(cart);
```

I would like the data `item_name`,`quantity`,`amount`,`total`,`subtotal`  to be stored in the array `cart` during each loop. However only the data in the last loop is being displayed in console. Why is this and why is not all the data stored in the array??

Comment: `cart` is not an array, it's an object in your case

Comment: `cart` is a object and you are overriding every time while iterating, so its resulting the last one.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide how come?? and does this mean it cannot store data

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee okay so what should I do?

Comment: stote in another array as most of the answers says. btw, why can't you directly use `items` array instead a copy of it?

Comment: and why you are depending on `for-loop`? you can use a map easily if you want to extract those properties only to a new array.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee `items` array is in another file thats why am not using it directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cart is not an array in your case it is an object, this would work in your case

```
var carts = [];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var cart = {};
    cart.item_name = items[i].get("item_name");
    cart.quantity = items[i].get("quantity");
    cart.amount =  items[i].get("amount");
    cart.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;
    cart.subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total;
    carts.push(cart);
}
console.log(carts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to declare cart as an array, you need to use [], then you are replacing the information inside the object in each iteration, so only last iteration is effective. you need to do something like this:

```
var cart = [];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var temp = {};
    temp.item_name = items[i].get("item_name");
    temp.quantity = items[i].get("quantity");
    temp.amount =  items[i].get("amount");
    temp.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;
    temp.subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total;
    cart.push(temp);
}
console.log(cart);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare an array and place the individuals cart inside it.

```
let carts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  let cart = {};
  cart.item_name = items[i].get("item_name");
  cart.quantity = items[i].get("quantity");
  cart.amount =  items[i].get("amount");
  cart.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;
  cart.subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total;
  carts.push(cart);
 }
console.log(carts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `Array` rather than an `Object`  and add each cart `Object` in this array with the `push()` method.

```
var carts = [];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var cart = {};
    cart.item_name = items[i].get("item_name");
    cart.quantity = items[i].get("quantity");
    cart.amount =  items[i].get("amount");
    cart.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;
    cart.subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total;
    carts.push(cart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an array of objects, you just have an object.

```
var cartItems = [];
var cartItem;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cartItem = {};
    cartItem.item_name = items[i].get("item_name");
    cartItem.quantity = items[i].get("quantity");
    cartItem.amount = items[i].get("amount");
    cartItem.total = cartItem.amount * cartItem.quantity;
    cartItem.subtotal = cartItem.subtotal + cartItem.total;
    cartItems.push(cartItem);
}
console.log(cartItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare cart as an array. Now the syntax for array would be like this

```
var cart = [];
```

and then declare the object in the loop like this

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var cart = {};
    cart.item_name = items[i].get("item_name");
    cart.quantity = items[i].get("quantity");
    cart.amount =  items[i].get("amount");
    cart.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;
    cart.subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total;
    carts.push(cart);
}
```